Unable to update the maven-core dependency version within the plugin maven-compiler-plugin
I'm trying to resolve a vulnerability (CVE-2021-26291) related to the dependency maven-core version 3.2.5, which is being pulled in by the build plugin maven-compiler-plugin version 3.12.1.
I tried following the official maven guide, by adding the version as follows:
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.12.1</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
                        <version>3.9.8</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

however I can still see the old version being pulled in when I run the  mvn dependency:resolve-plugins command:
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:maven-plugin:3.12.1
[INFO]       org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:3.12.1
[INFO]       org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:3.1.1
[INFO]       org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-exec:jar:1.6.0
[INFO]       org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.2.5 
[INFO]       org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:3.2.5


I'm not sure why it comes through as maven-site-plugin, though the version matches the one I indicate in the compiler, could it be because it is somehow nested within the compiler dependency? I do not make any direct reference to the maven-site-plugin in my pom.
Any help is very much appreciated as to why it behaves like this or if I'm doing something wrong. Thanks!

Which version of Maven are you using?

did you tried mvn dependency:tree?

The version used (maven-core) during the build  is provided by the runtime of your Maven version installed... (and running your build) also in such case I would recommend to upgrade to the most recent version of the plugins (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/)... 3.13.0 for the maven-compiler-plugin...Question: Maven version do you use?

As mentioned before upgrade the used Maven version... that is most important....greater than Maven 3.2.5.. best most recent 3.9.8(https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html)

I'm using Apache Maven 3.6.3. I have used the mvn dependency:tree command but it only lists the dependencies, not the plugins.

So the first step is to upgrade Maven 3.9.8 why such an old version does not make sense...

Please full pom file .... or an example project which help to reproduce this issue...

The mvn-site-plugin:3.12.1's POM contains:
...
<properties>
    <mavenVersion>3.2.5</mavenVersion>
...
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
      <version>${mavenVersion}</version>
...

I'd not expect to change its maven-core version just by changing it for the maven-compiler-plugin.
mvn-site-plugin's goals are bound to phases of the site lifecycle by default. Perhaps you (or someone else) ran the site lifecycle on the command line at least once in the past and you don't know/remember. ;)

The maven-core dependency is a dependency of the maven-compiler-plugin which is defined as minimum version for Maven supported.. (3.2.5)... but the real version is defined by the used Maven version itself during the build... The maven-compiler-plugin version 3.13.0 ... (https://github.com/apache/maven-compiler-plugin/blob/maven-compiler-plugin-3.13.0/pom.xml) references as minimum 3.6.3 as I mentioned in my comment before ... upgrade the plugin versions and use a most recent version of the plugin...

Thanks khmarbaise, unfortunately it didn't solve it. I updated the maven-compiler-plugin to 3.13.0, I've updated maven to 3.9.8, I tried purging dependencies and deleting my .m2 folder but nothing.. it's still pulling through maven-core 3.2.5

So you have another old plugin which requires that...upgrade all plugins to most recent versions https://maven.apache.org/plugins/ also it would be helpful to have your full pom file ... or maybe a link to private repo if you are not allowed to publish that in public...

I've tried updating everything but it will still pull it :( I can see that they mention the vulnerability in the maven-repo, and after reading this article I'm afraid this might be one of the repos still affected by the vulnerability. I think I will have to live with this one for now, I really appreciated the help!

Also very important because you are quoting the maven-site-plugin pom file... what you have missed that the dependency is defined as provided!!
